# How to use Memory<T> and Span<T> with Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I’ve been unable to get code that uses Span and Memory to compile for iOS using the latest build of Visual Studio for Mac 2019, with the c# language version set to Latest Version. I’ve come across conflicting instructions regarding this, which indicate that there is some complexity here (specifically, that Mono’s internal implementation was supplanted by a nuget package, or something to that effect.)

What do I need to do to get these types to compile correctly?

Comment: I am using the "preview" VS4M which includes Mono 5.18.1.24 and Xamarin.iOS
Version: 12.10.0.150 and have no problems using Span/Memory<T>  (no nuget, no manual changes to the `.csproj`, etc...)